# Show selectedchartValue in ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Don't know where to go from here.

I have a function:

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
    print("\(entry.value) in \(months[entry.xIndex])")
}
```

but can't imagine how to show only selected value. How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do it.

Take a look at ChartsDemo, click line chart, and there is a chart marker can show it;

If you want to do it, you can override `drawHighlighted` method, to draw the text you want.